# How to restart after making chnages to hosts.allow

Tags: ubuntu, host

I have made chnages /etc/hosts/allow like

```
ALL:ALL
```

I have to restart the whole computer to check that , is there any service which i can restart to check the setting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most services that use /etc/hosts.allow will notice changes to the file without a restart.

Comment: +1, or just restart the service you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the xinetd dameon and that should do.

Comment: Is there any alternative to a restart? Does xinetd pick up changes at runtime? Or is it possible – like with Apache – to send a special signal for a reload of all configuration files? In the world of containers, a restart may be disadvantageous.